# Erroneous spaces when concatenating string and integer in IDL

Tags: string, concatenation, idl-programming-language

Inputting the following four lines into the IDL console gives the output below.

```
IDL> num=123
IDL> str="bananas"
IDL> join=str+string(num)
IDL> print,join
bananas     123
```

Why are 5 spaces appearing in the string and how can I stop it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerical values are padded with leading blank spaces when converted with the `STRING` function.  Use `STRTRIM` instead.  The argument "2" removes both leading and trailing whitespace.

```
IDL> num=123
IDL> str="bananas"
IDL> join=str+STRTRIM(num,2)
IDL> print,join
bananas123
```

The [STRTRIM documentation](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/STRTRIM.html) explains more about the extra spaces.  [This page on formatted output](http://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/Format_Codes_Fortran.html) also has details on whitespace padding.